# Anyway to perform follow up actions in catch block from try block

Tags: java, exception, scope

I have a need to save a xml file in a directory .....if it is not well formed. 
Just to analyze it for the reason for the failure.

How do i save the xml request in a directory in catch block?

i tried doing it..but the variables created in the try block seems undefined in catch block. I am a newbie...sorry if its a basic question. any solutions?

```
  try {
  Create a well formed xml request
  open a http connection and post it
   }
  //catching all exceptions here
  catch (Exception e) {

  e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: `try-catch-finally`, although the `finally` block should be reserved for resource management

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The {} braces are [scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) the variables that are inside your try block, so they're not available outside of that scope.  You could do something like this:

```
String xml = null;
try {
  xml = ...; //Create a well formed xml request

  //open a http connection and post it
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (xml != null) {
        // write XML to file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define your variable outside/before the try block, you can use it inside the catch.  Really though, you should consider why you are using try/catch error handling as flow control.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable outside of the try block, then it would work

```
XmlDocument xml = null;
try {
  xml = Create a well formed xml request
  open a http connection and post it
}
catch (Exception e) {
  xml.save();
}
```

As you said, any variable declared inside the try block is not available in the catch block, so you have to place it outside

Answer (score 0):

if you create a new element in an inner block it is unreachable out of it.

So if you create something in try block it is just visible on it. You cannot reach that out of the block.

So for your problem you should create xml request out of  try block.
Something like this;

```
Create a well formed xml request
try {
    open a http connection and post it
}
//catching all exceptions here
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```